# Unable to check processes running on GPU with nvidia-smi, command not found and package not found

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics

im running on a DJI Manifold 2G (nvidia jetson tx2). However, i cant seem to access any nvidia tools. For instance,the nvidia-smi tool is missing, and i am unable to install it as well.

OS details :

```
DJI Manifold 2G
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 64 bit
7.7 GiB
ARMv8 Processor rev 3 (v8l) × 4 ARMv8 Processor rev 0 (v8l) × 2 
NVIDIA Tegra X2 (nvgpu)/integrated
```

```
nvidia-smi
bash: nvidia-smi: command not found
```

Trying sudo apt-get install does not work either.

```
dji@manifold2:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-smi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-smi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

When i type in nvidia- and use tab to autocomplete, i am given  these

```
dji@manifold2:~$ nvidia-
nvidia-bug-report-tegra.sh     nvidia-container-toolkit
nvidia-container-cli           nvidia-detector
nvidia-container-runtime       nvidia-docker
nvidia-container-runtime-hook
```

Does anyone know how might I check what's running on the GPU alternatively ?

Comment: sorry i missed that. I added it into the question details for my OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details about your GPU specs with deviceQuery utility in CUDA samples:

```
cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities//deviceQuery/
sudo make
./deviceQuery
```

Sourced from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283859/nvidia-smi-command-not-found-on-dji-manifold-2g-nvidia-jetson-tx2
Thanks @SeB